# Unable send mail on production getting erro Net::OpenTimeout (execution expired)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

Following is my production.rb file

config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true

config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'http://66.228.59.9'

config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "http://66.228.59.9" }

config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {

```
address: 'smtp.gmail.com',

port: 587,

domain: 'gmail.com',

user_name: 'email',

password: 'pasword',

authentication: :plain,
```

}

I am using ActionMailer. and Capistrano gem for deployment.

I am using Devise gem for authentication, and when user signup and confirmation mail is being sent I am getting this error. I have checked the server logs.

```
I, [2020-05-11T13:04:30.340191 #1022]  INFO -- : [2a6c5f94-0dfd-417c-8d0f-bf01fbb0e0f5] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 30184ms (ActiveRecord: 6.1ms)
F, [2020-05-11T13:04:30.341989 #1022] FATAL -- : [2a6c5f94-0dfd-417c-8d0f-bf01fbb0e0f5]   
F, [2020-05-11T13:04:30.342080 #1022] FATAL -- : [2a6c5f94-0dfd-417c-8d0f-bf01fbb0e0f5] Net::OpenTimeout (execution expired):
F, [2020-05-11T13:04:30.342110 #1022] FATAL -- : [2a6c5f94-0dfd-417c-8d0f-bf01fbb0e0f5]   
F, [2020-05-11T13:04:30.342137 #1022] FATAL -- : [2a6c5f94-0dfd-417c-8d0f-bf01fbb0e0f5] app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb:8:in `create'
```

Comment: are you using heroku? for production server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using LINODE server and was facing this issue.

I have found that LINODE, block the ports for some security concerns, I have rise the ticket and they unblock the ports, now I can send the mails.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would try would be to add the following option to your smtp settings hash:

```rb
enable_starttls_auto: true
```

It may simply be that you cannot even connect to the mail server due to not using TLS quite correctly.

If that doesn't work, it may be a case of needing to enable "Less Secure Access" for your gmail account, and/or setting an application password specific to just this web application.

From the [ActionMailer Rails guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#example-action-mailer-configuration):

> As of July 15, 2014, Google increased its security measures and now blocks attempts from apps it deems less secure. You can change your Gmail settings here to allow the attempts. If your Gmail account has 2-factor authentication enabled, then you will need to set an app password and use that instead of your regular password. Alternatively, you can use another ESP to send email by replacing 'smtp.gmail.com' above with the address of your provider.

Speaking personally, I'll typically use SendGrid (or another dedicated email provider) for my transactional emails, as GMail has strict limits on how much mail you can send, plus better reporting. It comes down to your needs and your budget, of course.